# Import Active Directory users and groups using Java

Tags: java, active-directory

I'm implementing a profiled (user / group) web application and I need to import into my application database all users and groups of my Active Directory. I'm running this application on Apache Tomcat under Ubuntu Server. I'd like to leave the import operation to some admin user direclty under my webapplication but, if it's not possible, I thought to use a .NET client to manager the user.

I saw on some tuturial it's possible to reach the windows domain controller using java to authenticathe the user but, in that case, I don't need to authenticate the user, I just need to recognize the group of user using the property

> System.getProperty("user.name")

to retrieve the user. I took a look to this tutorial:

http://gwallen.com/code/java/activedirectory.php

I tryied the first one but it doesn't works (LDAP: error code 49).

May you help me (suggesting me some tutorial or samples)?

thanks,
Andrea

Comment: LDAP error code 49 is 'invalid credentials'. Do you use correct security principal when trying to connect?

Comment: @mazaneicha just to understand, have I to use an admin user to login?

Comment: No - any user account is sufficient. The best way would create an service account that can not be used for computer logon (denied by Group policy).

Comment: @mazaneicha ok, I did and it was with this user I received error code 49

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query AD without password you need core Windows solution. E.g. you can run *dsquery* command

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Spring Security` to do so. Or just take a look at the classes which does so.